# Form with POST method still uses GET

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

I am making a user login / register system for a website I am making. In the `/register` page, I have a form, which is supposed to use the `POST` method, though it seems like it is using `GET`. After clicking `Sign Up`, it goes to this URL: `http://localhost:8080/zoweb/register/?first_name=my+first+name&last_name=my+last+name&username=my+username&email=my%40email.com&password=my+password&confirm_password=my+password&register=Sign+Up`. I am not using any JavaScript on this page, that I know of, that would affect this.

The form:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:</td><td><input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="John"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last name:</td><td><input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Smith"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Smithton"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td><td><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="john@smith.family"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Confirm password:</td><td><input type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <ul class="actions">
        <li><input name="register" value="Sign Up" type="submit" class="button special" /></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

The `register.php` page includes the following code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $fname =  $_POST['first_name'];
    $lname = $_POST['last_name'];
    $uname = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $confpass = $_POST['confirm_password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $good = 1;
    include('../connect.php');
    if (!$fname) {
        redir('./?error=first_name&errormsg=You must fill out all required forms.&showLogin=true');
        $good = 0;
    }

    if (!$email) {
        redir('./?error=email&errormsg=You must fill out all required forms.&showLogin=true');
        $good = 0;
    } elseif (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        redir('./?error=email&errormsg=Invalid email.&showLogin=true');
        $good = 0;
    }

    if (!$lname) {
        redir('./?error=last_name&errormsg=You must fill out all required forms.&showLogin=true');
        $good = 0;
    }

    if (!$uname) {
        redir('./?error=username&errormsg=You must fill out all required forms.&showLogin=true');
        $good = 0;
    }

    if (!$password) {
        redir('./?error=password&errormsg=You must fill out all required forms.&showLogin=true');
        $good = 0;
    }

    if ($confpass != $password) {
        redir('./?error=confirm_password&errormsg=You must fill out all required forms.&showLogin=true');
        $good = 0;
    }

    function redir($url)
    {
        header('Location: ' . $url);
    }

    if ($good == 1) {
        echo "Good.";

        $passwordhashoptions = [
            'cost' => 11,
            'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
        ];
        $passhash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $passwordhashoptions);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` IS '" . $uname . "';";
        $mysqli_result = $mysqli->query($query);
        echo "Result: " . $mysqli_result;
        if ($mysqli_result === FALSE) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO `webauth`.`users` (`username`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('" . $uname . "', '" . $fname . "', '" . $lname . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $passhash . "');";
            $mysqli->query($query);
            $emailcontent = "<style>
    #div {
        width:600px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        background-color: #cafff8;
        padding:5px;
        border-radius:10px;
        font-family:sans-serif;
    }
</style>
<div id='div'>Thankyou for registering at Zoweb. To confirm your account, just click the link below:<br><a href='http://localhost:8080/zoweb/register/confirm.php?code=xxx' style='color:black;text-decoration:underline;'>Verify</a></a></div>";
            $to = $email;
            $subject = "Confirm your account on Zoweb\r\n";
            $headers = "From: no-reply@zoweb.me\r\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
            mail($to, $subject, $emailcontent, $headers);
            header('Location: ./?error=none&errormsg=Please check your emails for confirmation.&showLogin=false&fname=' . $fname);
        } else {
            redir('./?error=fname');
        }
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

I think it might be possible that, for some reason, `register.php` is going back to `index.php`, but think not, as `register.php` does not have any redirections with the content in the form in it.

Comment: Maybe just a browser cache issue?

Comment: No, I've tried it on Chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE, with it not working on any.

Comment: Yeah, the form fields will be POSTED to register.php. On a different note: Use `<label for=""></label>` for your form fields to have accessibility. In your PHP code add a condition before setting variables, like so: `if(isset($_POST['password'])) { $password = $_POST['password']; }`

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` IS '" . $uname . "';";` Why did you write `IS` instead of `=` I wonder... Also, you're using MySQLi but you're not using prepared statements so you have a major security whole there! I could hack that form in 2 seconds.

Comment: Yeah - I'm going to fix all the security issues once I put it on the web, and the `IS` is just me forgetting that you use `=` not `IS`. And, couldn't you just do `$password = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : null`?

Comment: try this: create a new, empty PHP file, maybe `test.php` that only contains: `var_dump($_POST);` and change your form action to `test.php`. see if that works.

Comment: And by the way: did you create the `function redir($url)` inside your outer condition intentionally?

Comment: @burki (comment before this one) Yeah, I couldn't really be bothered to have to write `header('Location: ...')` every single time I redirected.

@burki (comment before the comment before this one) That still is doing the same thing (going to `localhost:8080/zoweb/register?first_name=...`) so I wonder if it actually is doing `GET`?

Comment: @Zoweb i undestand why you made a function, but i was wondering why you created it inside a condition?
About your (alleged?)  `GET`  problem: it really should not happen... have you ever created a form that `POST`ed correctly on your server?

Comment: Yes, I have. When I was working on the same thing, but didn't have the styling I do with this, it worked. I then completely rewrote the form when I remade the styling. And about the function, it's just because I put everything in the `if` statement, and I never moved the function out.

Comment: Check your page source in browser? Is it updating properly? Have you tried restarting your web server?

Comment: It is correct in the source code, and I have tried restarting Apache...

Comment: to see if something is redirecting after `register.php` is called, you could put a `die();`statement right at the top. That will at least tell you if the URL parameters are created from the `POST` event, or from something happening in your target page. Other than that, i could maybe imagine that your webserver or any framework you are using is intercepting your requests, but mostly, i am lost here. Sorry!

Comment: OK, it seems that `register.php` is included at the top of the page, so `die();` stops the whole page loading, but even if I remove it, there is still the problem of `POST` becoming `GET`. Even with `die();`, it does the `GET` stuff.

Comment: Wait... Are you doing URL rewriting? That's the most likely culprit if you are.

Comment: @harris No, I'm not.

Comment: Where the h... do you declare $mysqli in your code? Is this the whole code or a light version of it...?

Comment: How is it going if you remove all your "redir(...)" in your "errors" pieces of code? (just "forget" about the redir function and try please)

Comment: @Zoweb check if the data is properly posted to register.php or not for this you first need to place this little code right after the php tag starts
  <?php  echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);echo '</pre>';  ?>
This piece of code will show all the posted data at the register.php file then you will see either the data is posted successfully or not. ok